# Test automation using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Click method don't open the new page. My code trials as as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time    
drive.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\mvintee\project_for_selenium\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.verio.com/")
print(driver.title)
driver.find_element(By.ID,"stylesheet1").click()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Which element do you want to click? `stylesheet1` is representing the entire body tag.

Answer (score 0):

`(By.ID,"stylesheet1")` element represents the `<body>` element and ideally there is no point in clicking on the `<body>` element. Rather your usecase would be to click on <kbd>Login</kbd>

---

To click on the element <kbd>Login</kbd> you can use either of the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.verio.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.login-form > a[href*='/secure/login.html']").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: verio]

Comment: Any feedback about the solution provided?